# SPARQL - Subjects needed to complete the set

Tags: sparql

I am working on a new project using RDF, just learning it and SPARQL.  I thought this query would be easier than it is turning out to be.

Given this store (simplified out of the ontology)

```
Person1 -Owns->  Part1
Person2 -Owns->  Part1
Person2 -Owns->  Part2
Part1 -PartOf-> Product1
Part2 -PartOf-> Product1
```

I am trying to return all parts that a person needs to complete their product.

Given Person1, he needs Part2 to finish making Product1.
Given Person2, he needs nothing as he has all of the parts to make Product1.

I would like to return all persons and all needed parts for each product in 1 query, but thought to start smaller, just trying to find the parts that a specific person needs.  The real data has multiple products and parts that may be in multiple products (i.e. screws are in a lot of products) and persons that own parts that are partof multiple products.  Once I can get a subset query to work I should be able to extend it.

```
select ?parts
where 
{ 
  ?parts <PartOf> <Product1> .
  minus {<Person1> <Owns> ?parts}
}
```

My thought was get all of the parts that are part of Product1 and then eliminate the parts that Person1 owns.  But I am getting all of the parts in Product1. I tried a lot of other queries but this made the most logical sense to me after reading the tutorials and books.  Can someone point to where I am going wrong please?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

What query software are you using, and what does your data actually look like? I tried the following using [apache jena](http://jena.apache.org/):

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/> .

ex:person1 ex:owns ex:part1 .
ex:person2 ex:owns ex:part1 .
ex:person2 ex:owns ex:part2 .

ex:part1 ex:partOf ex:product1 .
ex:part2 ex:partOf ex:product1 .
```

and the query:

```
prefix ex: <http://example.com/>

select ?parts
where
{
    ?parts ex:partOf ex:product1
    minus { ex:person1 ex:owns ?parts }
}
```

Result:

```
$ arq --data data.ttl --query query.rq 
------------
| parts    |
============
| ex:part2 |
------------
```

Given what you've written either your query software is buggy (possible) but, more likely, you may have a simple typo in either your data or query. If (for example) you had 'owns' (lower case) rather than 'Owns' it would explain your result.

Try executing `{<Person1> <Owns> ?parts}` by itself. Do you get any results? Do any match the parts your query is returning?

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am using one of the RDBMS vendors implementation of RDF which uses Jena to access the store.  I inserted the data through Jena into the DBMS and am using Fuseki to work the SPARQL queries before placing them into Java.  I checked the case and the typing and it all looks correct.  I will validate one more time and then give my vendor rep a call.  perhaps he can help.  I always assume it is my problem before calling the vendor.

Comment: I talked with the vendor.  This is a current limitation in their SPARQL 1.1 support.  They also do not give an error about this limitation.  You gave me great insight - always try against arq as well.  Thanks so much.